# How does virtual memory maintains its efficiency?

Tags: c, system, virtual-memory

Given the large number of miss penalties, why doesn't paging affects or reduces the program performance? how is possible for virtual memory to be efficient?

Comment: What *is* that number of penalties you seem to know?

Comment: Paging *does* reduce a program's performance. It is statistically significant enough to always make sure you [warm up the cache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5063440/2564301) when doing performance tests.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't pose a programming problem. This is an operating system design question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By having enough RAM. Remember back in the day when you didn't, but ran large programs anyway? It wasn't fun.

Comment: @KerrekSB I read it in a book it just mentioned there are large number of miss penalties. And can anybody explain the downvotes?

Comment: The down votes are probably due to the fact that your question is off-topic on stackoverflow.com since your question doesn't have anything to do with programming or software development.  This is more of a operating system design or administration question and should be asked on one of those forums.  I've given an answer below anyways, but I am also voting to close this question because it is off-topic for this forum.

Comment: instead of the downvotes, would've been better if you guys had just commented about this issue, I would've happily removed it from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that **it does affect performance**.

Virtual memory is several orders of magnitude slower than main memory.  Usually, it's not noticed because many machines these days have oodles of memory and people rarely stress their machines all that much.  Remember, the VM system **ONLY** comes into play when the machine runs out of physical memory.  So a process that's been sleeping for awhile may have it's entire address space swapped out to disk while a process that needs more memory is currently running.  This is done in the background by the operating system.  So if you do a ps on Unix (using options like -ale or -ax depending on which Unix you are using), top (also Unix), or look in the Task Manager in Windows, there's usually quite a few processes that are sleeping or waiting for some event to occur.  Those are the ones that are targeted to have their memory swapped out to make room for programs that are actually running.  There are a whole bunch of optimizations that are done to make this as seamless as possible without affecting perceived performance all that much, if at all.

Now, when a system is really low on memory with applications asking for huge amounts of memory and multiple running processes, and when the system starts to swap pages in and out on each context switch (or most of them), then you get into the situation called (if I recall correctly) **Desperate Paging**.  You can easily identify this situation because the hard disk will start grinding (or thrashing) and the machine will be very sluggish.

This is where most bugs in the paging system become apparent because at this point, there is a high likelihood that the machine will either drop core on one or more offending programs, suffer a kernel panic, or a blue screen of death (on Windows systems).  This is why the easiest, cheapest, and most reliable way to significantly improve performance of any machine is to add memory.  Because, the more stuff you can keep in memory, the less paging that needs to be done.

The other optimization is to put (or move) the swap space or page file to the physical outer edge of the disk, if possible.  Hard drives spin at speeds of 3600, 5400, 7200, 10K RPMs or more (I've seen one at 14K RPM awhile back).  RPM is angular velocity, and data density is bits per square inch (or cm for metric).  The way the hard drives work these days, there are a variable number of sectors per track so the data density on the medium is constant.  The consequence of this is that the outside tracks have more data passing under the heads in one revolution than on the inside track.  So having the paging file on the outside track will help with system paging performance because you get more data passing the heads per unit of time.

For what it's worth, in my experience, the only times that I put my machine's balls to the wall was playing games like World of Warcraft or EvE Online.  In a corporate environment, you have servers whose performance is very sensitive to paging.  A large and busy SQL server with 64GB of RAM or more is not unheard of these days.  Even my Sun Fire T2000 server has 16GB of RAM in it which is more than most machines, and that was in 2007.

This is by no means a complete explanation, but I hope this answers your question.

Comment: "Thrashing" is the term I have seen used for the situation you call "Desperate Paging".

Comment: That describes the hard disk activity.  But I think the official term for the situation is what I have posted.  I'll add thrashing to my answer.